Moving a tab to anonther place in workbook takes a lot of time
I have a large workbook with about 20 worksheets containing formulas (mostly index match type) and a lot of data. When i try to move a worksheet to a different location in the workbook it takes a lot of time.
I have been working with large excel files for quite some time but i never experienced any significant loading time when moving a sheet to another place. Does anyone know what could cause this. Windows reports a high usage in memory and processor capacity
